# Overload Hospital Project C++

Tags: c++

all beginners and beyond masters, and friends.  I have an issue with evaluating what user inputs, the code seems working perfectly when you just type positive numbers, problem occurs when you type negative, it validates; and asks for re-entering values, but, after user re-enters new values it still keeps the old ones, and loop keeps being true (negative). Why the value of variable not changes? 
Here I am posting my code. I you interested yes it is related to my college assignment. Anyway I did much of code. The code just for you understand my question. Thanks a lot.

```
/*



 Write a program that computes and displays the charges for a patient’s hospital stay. First,
 the program should ask if the patient was admitted as an in-patient or an out-patient. If the
 patient was an in-patient the following data should be entered:
 • The number of days spent in the hospital
 • The daily rate
 • Charges for hospital services (lab tests, etc.)
 • Hospital medication charges.
 If the patient was an out-patient the following data should be entered:
 • Charges for hospital services (lab tests, etc.)
 • Hospital medication charges.
 Use a single, separate function to validate that no input is less than zero. If it is, it should
 be re-entered before being returned.
 Once the required data has been input and validated, the program should use two
 overloaded functions to calculate the total charges. One of the functions should accept
 arguments for the in-patient data, while the other function accepts arguments for out-
 patient data. Both functions should return the total charges.
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>



using namespace std;

void getJudgeData();
void inHospital();
void outHospital();
void checkIn(double dailyRate, double daysInHospital, double hospitalService, double hospitalMedication);
void checkOut(double hospitalService, double hospitalMedication);
void inQuestion();
void outQuestion();


double daysInHospital;
double dailyRate;
double hospitalService;
double hospitalMedication;
string patientType;
string name;






int main () {
    cout<<"What is your name? \n";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<"Are you IN patient or OUT\n (Type \"in\" or \"out\") \n ";
    cin>>patientType;
    patientType = patientType;

        if (patientType =="in") {
        inHospital();

    }
    else if (patientType =="out") {
        outHospital();

    }
    else {
    cout<<"Please run again! Probably you didn't enter in or out correctly in lower case!";
    }



    return 0;


}



void inHospital() {
    inQuestion();

    checkIn(dailyRate, daysInHospital, hospitalService, hospitalMedication);

    cout<<  "Dear Mr "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<  "Your bill is described below         : \n";
    cout<<  "You are the patient type             : "<<patientType<<endl;
    cout<< "Total days you stayed at hospital is  : " << daysInHospital<<endl;
    cout<<"Your daily Rate is                     : $" <<dailyRate<<endl;
    cout<<"Total for Hospital service is         : $"<<hospitalService<<endl;
    cout<<"Total for Hospital Medication is      : $"<<hospitalMedication<<endl;
    cout<<"Grand total is                         : "<< (daysInHospital*dailyRate+hospitalMedication+hospitalService) <<endl;

}

void outHospital() {

    outQuestion();

    checkOut(hospitalService, hospitalMedication);

    cout<<"Dear Mr "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Your bill is described below      \t: \n";
    cout<<"You are the patient type          \t: "<<patientType<<endl;
    cout<<"Total for Hospital service is       \t: $"<<hospitalService<<endl;
    cout<<"Total for Hospital Medication is    \t: $"<<hospitalMedication<<endl;
    cout<<"Grand total is                      \t: $"<< (hospitalMedication+hospitalService) <<endl;

}



// ************ CHECH or VALIDATION PART************

void checkIn(double dailyRate, double daysInHospital, double hospitalService, double hospitalMedication) {

    while (dailyRate<0 || daysInHospital<0 || hospitalService<0 || hospitalMedication<0) {
        cout<< "Please re-enter the values they must not be less than 0 \n";
        inQuestion();

    }
}



void checkOut(double hospitalService, double hospitalMedication) {

    while (hospitalService<0 || hospitalMedication<0) {
        outQuestion();
        cout<<hospitalMedication<<endl;
        cout<<hospitalService<<endl;

    }

}

// ********* QUESTIONS FOR ASK
void inQuestion() {

    cout<< "How many days spent in hospital? "<<endl;
    cin>> daysInHospital;

    cout<< "What is the daily rate for IN Patient \n";
    cin>>dailyRate;

    cout<<"What is amount of charges for hospital services?  \n";
    cin>>hospitalService;

    cout<<"Hospital medication charges?  \n";
    cin>>hospitalMedication;
}

void outQuestion() {
    cout<<"What is amount of charges for hospital services?  \n";
    cin>>hospitalService;

    cout<<"Hospital medication charges?  \n";
    cin>>hospitalMedication;
}
```

Comment: No, I already tried that one. It just don't change the variable. I printed out the variables I am changing, and it prints them right but at the end it adds the first negative number which I typed previously..  Can it be because I ame using XCode, on MACOSx

Comment: You have variables with the same name both as global variables and function parameters. Remove the function parameters and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some global variables and you pass them as parameters. The function where the variables are passed to shadows the variables with the parameters. Your global variables are changed, but you keep checking for the parameters. Since your functions will see the global variables anyway, let's not pass them as parameters:

```
/*



 Write a program that computes and displays the charges for a patient’s hospital stay. First,
 the program should ask if the patient was admitted as an in-patient or an out-patient. If the
 patient was an in-patient the following data should be entered:
 • The number of days spent in the hospital
 • The daily rate
 • Charges for hospital services (lab tests, etc.)
 • Hospital medication charges.
 If the patient was an out-patient the following data should be entered:
 • Charges for hospital services (lab tests, etc.)
 • Hospital medication charges.
 Use a single, separate function to validate that no input is less than zero. If it is, it should
 be re-entered before being returned.
 Once the required data has been input and validated, the program should use two
 overloaded functions to calculate the total charges. One of the functions should accept
 arguments for the in-patient data, while the other function accepts arguments for out-
 patient data. Both functions should return the total charges.
 */
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>



using namespace std;

void getJudgeData();
void inHospital();
void outHospital();
void checkIn();
void checkOut();
void inQuestion();
void outQuestion();


double daysInHospital;
double dailyRate;
double hospitalService;
double hospitalMedication;
string patientType;
string name;






int main () {
    cout<<"What is your name? \n";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<"Are you IN patient or OUT\n (Type \"in\" or \"out\") \n ";
    cin>>patientType;
    patientType = patientType;

        if (patientType =="in") {
        inHospital();

    }
    else if (patientType =="out") {
        outHospital();

    }
    else {
    cout<<"Please run again! Probably you didn't enter in or out correctly in lower case!";
    }



    return 0;


}



void inHospital() {
    inQuestion();

    checkIn();

    cout<<  "Dear Mr "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<  "Your bill is described below         : \n";
    cout<<  "You are the patient type             : "<<patientType<<endl;
    cout<< "Total days you stayed at hospital is  : " << daysInHospital<<endl;
    cout<<"Your daily Rate is                     : $" <<dailyRate<<endl;
    cout<<"Total for Hospital service is         : $"<<hospitalService<<endl;
    cout<<"Total for Hospital Medication is      : $"<<hospitalMedication<<endl;
    cout<<"Grand total is                         : "<< (daysInHospital*dailyRate+hospitalMedication+hospitalService) <<endl;

}

void outHospital() {

    outQuestion();

    checkOut();

    cout<<"Dear Mr "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Your bill is described below      \t: \n";
    cout<<"You are the patient type          \t: "<<patientType<<endl;
    cout<<"Total for Hospital service is       \t: $"<<hospitalService<<endl;
    cout<<"Total for Hospital Medication is    \t: $"<<hospitalMedication<<endl;
    cout<<"Grand total is                      \t: $"<< (hospitalMedication+hospitalService) <<endl;

}



// ************ CHECH or VALIDATION PART************

void checkIn() {

    while (dailyRate<0 || daysInHospital<0 || hospitalService<0 || hospitalMedication<0) {
        cout<< "Please re-enter the values they must not be less than 0 \n";
        inQuestion();

    }
}



void checkOut() {

    while (hospitalService<0 || hospitalMedication<0) {
        outQuestion();
        cout<<hospitalMedication<<endl;
        cout<<hospitalService<<endl;

    }

}

// ********* QUESTIONS FOR ASK
void inQuestion() {

    cout<< "How many days spent in hospital? "<<endl;
    cin>> daysInHospital;

    cout<< "What is the daily rate for IN Patient \n";
    cin>>dailyRate;

    cout<<"What is amount of charges for hospital services?  \n";
    cin>>hospitalService;

    cout<<"Hospital medication charges?  \n";
    cin>>hospitalMedication;
}

void outQuestion() {
    cout<<"What is amount of charges for hospital services?  \n";
    cin>>hospitalService;

    cout<<"Hospital medication charges?  \n";
    cin>>hospitalMedication;
}
```

Comment: That will not work as if all won't be true it will return false but user could input just one of them negative so. That's why I used || . Thanks.

Comment: @JohnHaggin it is difficult to find out what your intentions are, we can only guess without their specification. You described the behavior you experience in your question, but not your intention.

Comment: Let me try to explain, I am letting to user to enter 4  numbers, they must be positive and if user enters just one of them negative it should ask again. But In my case it ask again however doesn't assign entered value to the variable. It keeps the first entered negative number. Doesn't let me change it.

Comment: @JohnHaggin do you mean dailyRate remains negative? Is checkIn or checkOut called?

Comment: @JohnHaggin which is the loop you are having problem with and how should it behave?

Comment: Lajos Arpad, That's right, I am calling both check on its places, but anyway it doesn't change the variables value. You understand me.

Comment: check loops should check that user entered positive number if not, it asks again same questions, after it must stop asking because user enters all positive numbers, however it doesn't break the loop and continues.

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: @JohnHaggin the issue was that you have global variables, but if you use the same name as a parameter of a function, then it overshadows it. You have your global double daysInHospital; but it was also a parameter of checkIn. Inside checkIn when you refer daysInHospital, you use the parameter, not the global variable and the parameter value remained unchanged even though you successfully changed the value of the global variable. The solution was to not use the given parameter, so the while will check the global variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this lab as well. Mine functions perfectly in Visual Studio 2017 and Global Variables are not needed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void inpatient(bool&, int&, double&, double&, double&, double&); 
void outpatient(bool&, double&, double&, double&);

int main()
{   
    bool patient; //if bool is true, the patient in an inpatient. If false, the patient is an outpatient
    int days; //days spent in hospital
    double rate, //daily rate for inpatient
           medCharge_IP, //inpatient medication charges
           hsCharge_IP, //inpatient hospital services charges
           medCharge_OP, //outpatient medication charges
           hsCharge_OP, // outpatient hospital services charges
           totalCharge; //total charges of hospital stay

    cout << "If the patient admitted was an in - patient, please enter 1. If the patient was an out - patient, please enter 0" << endl; 
    cin >> patient;

    if (patient == true) //If the boolean variable is true, the program will see the patient as an inpatient
    {   
        inpatient(patient, days, rate, medCharge_IP, hsCharge_IP, totalCharge); //Returns the variable data
        cout << "The total charges for the hospital visit accumulate to " << totalCharge << " dollars." << endl;
    }

    if (patient == false) //If the boolean variable is false, the program will see the patient as an outpatient
    {
        outpatient(patient, medCharge_OP, hsCharge_OP, totalCharge); //Returns the variable data
        cout << "The total charges for the hospital visit accumulate to " << totalCharge << " dollars." << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE"); //This is needed because on some computers, the program will finish too fast
    return 0;
}

void inpatient(bool& patient, int& days, double& rate, double& medCharge_IP, double& hsCharge_IP, double& totalCharge)
{
    cout << "How many days did the patient spend in the hospital ?" << endl;
    cin >> days;
    if (days < 0) //A validation check is required in the program requirements 
    {   cout << "How many days did the patient spend in the hospital ? (Only positive numbers allowed)" << endl;
        cin >> days;    }

    cout << "What is the daily rate for an inpatient stay ?" << endl;
    cin >> rate;
    if (rate < 0) //A validation check is required in the program requirements
    {   cout << "What is the daily rate for an inpatient stay ? (Only positive numbers allowed)" << endl;
        cin >> rate;    }

    cout << "What were the medication charges for the stay ?" << endl;
    cin >> medCharge_IP;
    if (medCharge_IP < 0) //A validation check is required in the program requirements
    {   cout << "What were the medication charges for the stay ? (Only positive numbers allowed)" << endl;
        cin >> medCharge_IP;    }

    cout << "What were the charges for hospital services ?" << endl;
    cin >> hsCharge_IP;
    if (hsCharge_IP < 0) //A validation check is required in the program requirements
    {   cout << "What were the charges for hospital services ? (Only positive numbers allowed)" << endl;
        cin >> hsCharge_IP;     }

    totalCharge = (days*rate) + hsCharge_IP + medCharge_IP; //calculating the total charges for an inpatient stay
}

void outpatient(bool& patient, double& medCharge_OP, double& hsCharge_OP, double& totalCharge)
{
    cout << "What were the medication charges for the stay ?" << endl;
    cin >> medCharge_OP;
    if (medCharge_OP < 0) //A validation check is required in the program requirements
    {   cout << "What were the medication charges for the stay ? (Only positive numbers allowed)" << endl;
        cin >> medCharge_OP;    }

    cout << "What were the charges for hospital services ?" << endl;
    cin >> hsCharge_OP;
    if (hsCharge_OP < 0) //A validation check is required in the program requirements
    {   cout << "What were the charges for hospital services ? (Only positive numbers allowed)" << endl;
        cin >> hsCharge_OP;     }

    totalCharge = hsCharge_OP + medCharge_OP; //calculating the total charges for an outpatient stay

}
```